# Cannot upload files to private file system using s3fs

Tags: 7

We have migrated our Drupal 7 site to AWS with S3 bucket. Integrated s3 bucket with the site using s3fs module. We have made all the necessary configurations. We are having issue uploading files to private file system

We tried with each of the following as Default download method. 
 - Amazon Simple Storage Service
 - Public files served from Amazon S3.
 - Private files served from Amazon S3

We are receiving error the following error

```
Guzzle\Common\Exception\RuntimeException: Error creating resource. [message] fopen(https://xxxx.xxx.s3bucketpath/s3fs-private/XXXX.docx): failed to open stream: "DrupalRemoteStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed [file] /var/app/current/sites/all/libraries/awssdk2/Guzzle/Stream/PhpStreamRequestFactory.php [line] 217 in Guzzle\Stream\PhpStreamRequestFactory->createResource() (line 279 of /var/app/current/sites/all/libraries/awssdk2/Guzzle/Stream/PhpStreamRequestFactory.php)
```

Just to add a note on this we are using file field path module for the field. This patch (https://www.drupal.org/node/2527768) seems to be for older version of File field path module

Answer (score 0):

Check on PHP's setting for `allow_url_fopen` ... it's generally turned off by security-aware system administrators, which will block `fopen`'s ability to access to resources over http(s).

Answer (score 0):

I had an exact problem and turned out it was a firewall issue. Everytime I `requested /admin/config` and `/admin/reports/status` I always got the same error.

This error happened around the time when our company implemented our own firewall. 
So after pulling out all the hair, I found out that our company's firewall had its own certificate (.pem) file for in out requests. 
Guzzle has its own pem certificate in its resource so in the `guzzlehttp/src/Guzzle/Http/Resources/cacert.pem`, I appended our own certificate. and the error was gone.